# How to add web page in windows forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am having one Form "**email.cs**"  in my project name as "**Email Client**"

In that form I am having one LinkLabel Control name as "**Verify Email Address**"

I designed one web Page name as "**Verify.aspx**".In this web page I have one TextBox Control

and one Button Control. When I enter any address into the textBox and click on the button it

immediately checks whether the email address entered into the textBox is actually present or

not on the "**GMAIL-SERVER**".

So my **Question** is that How can I Add this **Web-Page** into my **Windows-Forms Project**

Comment: Have you considered a different (simpler) approach - just have your Windows Form and from your C# code make the relevant HTTP request to the Gmail server? No need for a web page at all.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail

Comment: It's difficult to offer detailed help without knowing more about your exact requirements and to know why you are trying to do what you describe in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some effort into this before asking on SO, try searching online and look at examples (For example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s8ys666%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). You can just add a `WebControl` to the form.

You can use `Regex` to validate email addresses or try the following.

```
//NOTE: This code will not catch double periods, extra spaces. For more precision, stick to Regex.
public bool IsEmailValid(string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `Regex` way to validate Email address:

```
String email = "test@gmail.com";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*"
+ "@"
+ @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$";);
Match match = regex.Match(email);
if (match.Success)
    //Email is has the right format.
else
    //Email doesn't have the correct format.
```

But if your goal is to communicate with Gmail, then you will need to make use of:

GMAIL APIs - https://developers.google.com/gmail/